# Application No Longer Loads on Windows 10 Build 1803 (April 2018 Update)

Tags: c++, windows-10, windows-update

Our C++ applications are not loading via network share since upgrading workstations to Windows 10 build 1803. The following error is shown:

```
---------------------------
HELLO.EXE - Application Error
---------------------------
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00000ba). Click OK to close the application. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Starting the application through the VS2015 debugger withg Application Verifier running gives the following exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA2B86624E (combase.dll) in hello.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.


=======================================
VERIFIER STOP 0000000000000013: pid 0x22B4: First chance access violation for current stack trace. 

    0000000000000000 : Invalid address causing the exception.
    00007FFA2B86624E : Code address executing the invalid access.
    0000003A49B4D5F0 : Exception record.
    0000003A49B4D100 : Context record.


=======================================
This verifier stop is continuable.
After debugging it use `go' to continue.

=======================================


The call stack looks as follows:

    vrfcore.dll!VerifierStopMessageEx() Unknown
    vrfcore.dll!VfCoreRedirectedStopMessage(unsigned __int64,char *,unsigned __int64,char *,unsigned __int64,char *,unsigned __int64,char *,unsigned __int64,char *)    Unknown
    verifier.dll!VerifierStopMessage()  Unknown
    verifier.dll!AVrfpVectoredExceptionHandler()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatch() Unknown
>   combase.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::Create() Line 1445    C++
    combase.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::StaticInitialize() Line 1421  C++
    combase.dll!`dynamic initializer for 'Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<1> >::isInitialized''() Line 1528 C++
    ucrtbase.dll!_initterm()    Unknown
    combase.dll!dllmain_crt_process_attach(HINSTANCE__ * const instance, void * const reserved) Line 65 C++
    combase.dll!dllmain_dispatch(HINSTANCE__ * const instance, const unsigned long reason, void * const reserved) Line 194  C++
    verifier.dll!AVrfpStandardDllEntryPointRoutine()    Unknown
    vrfcore.dll!VfCoreStandardDllEntryPointRoutine(void *,unsigned long,struct _CONTEXT *)  Unknown
    vfbasics.dll!AVrfpStandardDllEntryPointRoutine()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeNode()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!AVrfInitializeVerifier()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeProcess()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitialize() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpInitialize()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk()  Unknown
```

The application still runs in previous builds of Windows 10 and also the app will run if I enable Windows 8 compatibilty mode.

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to why windows is unable to start the process?

Thanks,
Steve.

Comment: Please consider removing the C++ tag and/or posting this on SuperUser or similar. Avoid cross posting. Or provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why? The application is written in C++ and that could be the detail required to solve the problem.

Comment: You'll need to reduce your code to a [mcve] - the backtrace isn't much use without the code!

Comment: To the downvoters:  This may not be a great question, but it *has* been actively useful - my company has a similar problem, and having the question here was useful to us.

Comment: Hi Martin. Have you made any progress with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

We've finally identified the cause. We had a folder named propsys.dll that had been created at some point in the past when downloading symbols. Removing the folder has resolved the issue. It would appear the latest build of Windows 10 is trying to access the folder as a DLL.